# VBA - How to select specific charts in excel and paste them on single slide in power point

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have the following code:

```
Sub Export_Allcahrts_ppt()
  Dim mypowerpoint As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim mypowerpoint_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim myslide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim mychart As ChartObject

  Set mypowerpoint = New PowerPoint.Application
  mypowerpoint.Visible = msoTrue
  Set mypowerpoint_pres = mypowerpoint.Presentations.Add
  Set myslide = mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
  For Each mychart In Sheet1.ChartObjects
    mychart.Copy
    myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
    With myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)
      .Top = 100
      .Height = 200
      .Left = 30
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

How to select specific charts like chart 1 in sheet 1, chart 2 in sheet 2 in excel and paste them on a single slide in powerpoint?

Comment: Hi...someone help to modify the above code where i can copy charts from different sheets and paste then on single slide in power point ...thanks

Comment: You can select and copy charts in Excel by using their names.  .charts("Chart1").copy

Comment: i am looking to copy charts from different sheets in excel and paste on single slide in power point.

Comment: How are the charts named?  Chart1, Chart2, Chart3?

Comment: charts had specific names like "Direct Sales texas","Direct Sales California"..so on

Comment: Then you will have code those names into your VBA code or somehow get the names into VBA so you only choose those charts.

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate through all sheets in workbook, then just check for the charts you are looking for.  If the charts are named like chart1 on sheet1, then.....

```
Set wb as activeworkbook
For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    'check for name of chart, if statements or a case select statement.
    if cht.name = "Chart" & sht.index then

        'Copy to PPT
    end if

  Next cht
Next sht
```